# What is the difference between a Graphical Calculation View with star join and a normal calculation view in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

As we all know we have an option of Star join while creating a Graphical Calculation View in SAP HANA.

I can implement the exact same thing without using this star join feature by implementing multiple joins in a Graphical CV.
Is there any advantage of Star join over it??
Why do we have this option?

PS: I am not using any analytical and attribute views im both scenarios.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The star join is a modeling artifact specifically aimed at supporting star and snowflake Schemas.
The main difference to arbitrary joins is that the star schema assumes a central fact table that contains all key figures that should be aggregated, while all selection criteria are defined on dimension tables that are then joined to the fact table.
This is a very different approach for both optimizing the query as thinking about the relationships between the involved tables.

Generally speaking, if you have a star schema, you want to use the star join for better performance and a more expressive model. If you don’t have a star schema then it’s likely the wrong choice for your model.

Answer (score 0):

Star joins in calculation views help join a fact table with dimensional data. The fact table contains data that represent business facts such as, price, discount values, number of units sold, and more. Dimension tables represent a collection of information. The information can include entities such as, geography, time intervals, contact names and more.

Refer below link

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/13/hana-sp07-star-join/